# Yii - Client Side Validation for Textarea

Tags: php, validation, yii, active-form

I am new to yii and having trouble with client side validation for my textarea. I am not sure what I am doing wrong but for some reason the client side validation does not work only for this textarea.

Below is my rules in my model:

```
public function rules()
{
    return array(
        array('content', 'required'),
        array('user_id, seen', 'numerical', 'integerOnly'=>true),
        array('datetime', 'safe'),
        array('id, user_id, content, datetime, seen', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
    );
}
```

Here is the code in my view:

```
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('TbActiveForm', array(
        'id'=>'post-form',
        'action'=>Yii::app()->createUrl('/feedback/default/create'),
        'enableClientValidation'=>true,
        'clientOptions'=>array(
            'validateOnSubmit'=>true,
        ),
    )); ?>
    <div class="modal-header">
        <a class="close" id="close_modal" onclick="idEmpty(event)">&times;</a>
        <h4>New Feedback</h4>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-body">
        <?php echo $form->textarea($model,'content', array('id'=>'feedback_content','class'=>'feedback_textarea')); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'content'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-footer">
        <div class="hint" style="float:left">
            <span style="color:red;font-weight: bold">Hint: </span>You can use <?php echo CHtml::link('markdown', 'http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax'); ?> syntax!
        </div>
        <?php echo TbHtml::submitButton('Send Feedback', array('color' => TbHtml::BUTTON_COLOR_SUCCESS)); ?>
    </div>

<?php 
    $this->endWidget();
?>
```

and finally this is my controller:

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model=new Feedback;
    if(isset($_POST['Feedback'])) {
        $model->attributes = $_POST['Feedback'];
        $model->user_id = Yii::app()->user->getId(); 
        $model->datetime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        $model->seen = 0;
        if($model->validate()) {
            $model->save();
            $this->redirect(array('/dashboard'));
        }
        else
            echo 'cant validate';
    }

}
```

If I try to violate the rule for this textarea, like if I leave it blank, I do not get the proper error message and I end up getting "can't validate" (which is only there for testing purposes). My database is mysql and the intended field is of type "TEXT".

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: add this to your view and it will show you the messages from failed validations:

echo $form->errorSummary($model);

Comment: or  try this : `if($model->validate()) {
 ....
 }
 else {
      $errors = $model->getErrors();
      var_dump($errors); //or print_r($errors)
      exit;
 }`

Comment: Hi Ronit, Thank you for your reply. I tried your second suggestion and var_dump($errors) returns the error message. I still wonder though, why I dont get the error message on the client side, meaning why I can't see the error message instantly in my form.

Comment: so what is the returned error

Comment: Nothing. Upon submitting the form, I am redirected to /feedback/default/create where I see what var_dump($errors) returns in a blank page

Comment: just go directly to /feedback/default/create directly you will get error

Comment: Nope, I don't get any errors..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `'id'=>'feedback_content'` from `$form->textarea()`. CActiveForm it self will create the ID for a form filed. For your text area id should be `Feedback_content` not `feedback_content` (Case sensitive). Because of this may be validation message is not  notifying in the view. Put `errorSummary` to check the validation

```
 <?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>
```

Comment: That was it. Removing the id solved the issue. Thanks.